# LDAP userSearchFilter By group

Tags: ldap, ldap-query, usergroups

I trying to reconfigure the ldap authentication for Active Directory as I found the current version of search filter are too long. The example of current version of search filter that working:

> AUTHENTICATION_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY.userSearchFilter=(&(sAMAccountName={0})(|(memberof=CN=EG1,OU=APP,OU=Global,OU=Group1,DC=company,DC=com)(memberof=CN=EG2,OU=APP,OU=Global,OU=Group1,DC=company,DC=com)(memberof=CN=EG3,OU=APP,OU=Global,OU=Group1,DC=company,DC=com)))
>   AUTHENTICATION_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY.userSearchBase=DC=company,DC=com

How can I reduce the search filter declaration? The EG1,EG2,EG3 are under APP.

Comment: Define 'too long'. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You could use nested groups. Have one group with all the EG groups as members; then the filter only needs to check the top group for membership.

Comment: @ryan problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to @ryan for the comment.
Basically create a group named parentgroup and merge EG1,EG2,EG3 into the parentgroup.

So my working searchfilter:

```
AUTHENTICATION_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY.userSearchFilter=(&(sAMAccountName={0})(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=parentgroup,OU=APP,OU=Global,OU=Group1,DC=company,DC=com))
AUTHENTICATION_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY.userSearchBase=DC=company,DC=com
```